# Method of asking question

Tags: adjectives, questions

> How many micron plastic bag is allowed to be used in your country?
>
> How many micron(thick)plastic bag is allowed to be used in your country?

By this I mean to ask, what is the allowed thickness of plastic bag in country. Some countries doesn’t allow plastic bags with thickness above a certain rate to be used.

In these question if I add “thick” before “plastic bag” as ist case with my second sentence.would it be more grammatical or unnatural? I couldn’t be sure if I should add it or not in sentence I saw in a article.

And Is the first sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I suggest you look this up on the internet before asking it here. Please also correct your spelling and grammar. Some countries, not some country, here. Finally, also review measurements. "How many micron plastic bag" is gibberish. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your polite advice.

Comment: [some countries don't]  thick, not thic.[as is the case]

Comment: Thanks for the very critical correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't care about microns, you are asking about thickness. This means that you don't need use the units of measurement. Provided you have established that you are talking about the regulations for bags, then:

> What is the maximum thickness of plastic permitted for bags in your country?

This is a typical XY problem, and in fact you had already solved it because

> What is the allowed thickness of plastic bags in your country

would also be a correct way to ask.  However it is not clear what "how many micron thick plastic bag" is talking about, so don't use that type of question.

Comment: I couldn’t understand why we can’t say “how many micron platic bag “while we can say “five micron plastic bag”?

Comment: You can, if you have established the context of "I'm talking about the technical subject of plastic film thicknesses"  Its is just that normal people don't talk about the thickness of plastic sheets. So if you are asking about how thinck plastic bags are, you should ask "How thick..." and not "How many microns".     This is a clear case of you thinking about the grammar and forgetting the meaning that you want to ask.